# dpkg error (1) while Installing anything

Tags: dpkg

Whenever I try to install something I always get this exact error.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/steam_1%3a1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Doing `sudo apt-get -f install` doesn't do anything, so could someone help me?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get autoclean` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory`/var/cache/apt/archives/` is where the .deb files that `apt` downloads are stored. Once you have installed the respective programs, you can delete the .deb's, but that should be done with the command `sudo apt-get clean`.

Comment: Now I have this problem. http://pastebin.com/7Y4ndF6d

Comment: Reboot, then run `sudo apt-get clean` and try again.